# Calculate the first variation of $\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+|\frac{dy}{dx}|^2}~dx$ by considering a parameterisation of y and x

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

So i've been given this job, i could use some help please.

This is what i have so far:

$$J(x,y,y') = \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right|^{2}} dx \implies $$
$$J(t,x,y,\dot{x},\dot{y}) = \int_{0}^{1} \Phi (t,x,y,\dot{x},\dot{y})~dt=\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}~dt$$

we have that $$\delta J(x,y;h_1,h_2) = \int_{0}^{1} h_1 \left[\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{d \Phi }{d\dot{x}}\right] + h_2 \left[\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{d \Phi }{d\dot{y}}\right]~dt$$ 
Based on the idea that $$\delta K(x,u,u';h) = \int_{a}^{b} \left[ \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial u}(x,u,u')v + \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial u'}(x,u,u')v'\right] = \int_{a}^{b} \left[ \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial u} - \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial u'}\right]~dx$$
$$\delta J(x,y;h_1,h_2) = \int_{0}^{1} h_1 \left[\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{d \Phi }{d\dot{x}}\right] + h_2 \left[\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{d \Phi }{d\dot{y}}\right]~dt $$
$$= \int_{a}^{b} h_1 \left[ - \frac{\dot{y}(\ddot{x}\dot{y}-\dot{x}\ddot{y})}{(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)^{3/2}} \right] +h_2 \left[ - \frac{\dot{x}(\ddot{y}\dot{x}-\dot{y}\ddot{x})}{(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)^{3/2}} \right] dt = \int_{a}^{b} \frac{\ddot{x}\dot{y}(h_2 \dot{x}-h_1 \dot{y}) + \ddot{y}\dot{x}(h_1\dot{y}-h_2 \dot{x})}{(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)^{3/2}} dt$$

this entire thing seems needlessly complicated to me, where am i going wrong? is the above correct or should i just recalculate using 
$$\delta j(\mathbf{u};\mathbf{v}) = \left.\frac{d}{dt} J(\mathbf{u}+t\mathbf{v})\right|_{t=0}$$?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation looks correct (assuming, of course, that your derivatives are fine, which I did not check). However, notice that there's no point in merging $h_1$ and $h_2$ inside a single integral. They are merely helper functions to aid your expansion.

What you need to calculate is $\frac{\delta J}{\delta x(t')}$ and $\frac{\delta J}{\delta y(t')}$, which you find by letting $h_1(t) \to \delta(t'-t)$ and $h_2(t) \to \delta(t'-t)$, so by removing these $h$'s your solution simplifies a bit.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer. Next, if i remember right, $\delta(t'-t) = 0$ for $t' \neq t$ so would i make the assumption then that $h_{1}, h_{2} = t$ as any other time would be 0, substitute that value in and then cancel?

Comment: Not really cancel, but get out of the integral. The property of the delta function is $\int_a^b f(t)\delta(t-t')dt = f(t')$. Remember this, it's very important!

Comment: Sorry about this, ill ask this last question then go to sleep (after setting your answer as accepted)
if im following then
$$\int_{a}^{b} \delta(t-t') \left[ - \frac{\dot{y}(\ddot{x}\dot{y}-\dot{x}\ddot{y})}{(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)^{3/2}} \right] +\delta(t-a) \left[ - \frac{\dot{x}(\ddot{y}\dot{x}-\dot{y}\ddot{x})}{(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)^{3/2}} \right] dt = \frac{-\ddot{x}\dot{y}^2+\dot{x}\ddot{y}\dot{y}-\dot{x}^2\ddot{y}+\dot{x}\dot{y}\ddot{x})}{(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{\dot{x}\dot{y}(\ddot{y}+\ddot{x}) - (\ddot{x}\dot{y}^2+\dot{y}\ddot{x}^2)}{(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: where the values of $\dot{x}$ etc is equal to $t'$, this doesnt seem like much of an improvement at this point so i imagine i'm missing something. Alternatively if it's just me over thinking it, by all means please say so.

Comment: Notice that there are two functional derivatives. One is with respect to x(t). For this derivative, you set $h_1$ to the delta function and $h_2$ to 0. For the derivative with respect to $y(t)$ it's the other way around.

Comment: hmmm it occurs to me that perhaps my lecture notes are not very in depth on this subject... for example they dont mention needing to calculate $\frac{\delta j}{\delta x(t')}$ or $\frac{\delta j}{\delta y(t')}$. My apologies for the continuous questioning but i think its clear at this point i'm in need of some real explanation. (whilst i continue my research on this topic) to the point that although i'm certain you're correct i'm unsure of what youre trying to guide me too.

Comment: your comments suggest setting $h_1 = \delta(t-t')$, doing so would yield $$\frac{\delta J}{\delta x(t')}=\int_{0}^{1}\delta(t-t')\left(-\frac{\dot{y}(\ddot{x}\dot{y}-\dot{x}\ddot{y})}{(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)^{3/2}}\right)+0~dt = -\frac{\dot{y}(t')(\ddot{x}(t')\dot{y}(t')-\dot{x}(t')\ddot{y}(t'))}{(\dot{x}(t')^2+\dot{y}(t')^2)^{3/2}}$$ and similiar for $\frac{\delta J}{\delta y(t')}$ assuming my calculations are correct..what now? i've seen (for example on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) that theres definitions of $\delta j$ (which i assume i'm meant to be calculating) which

Comment: $$\delta J = \int_{a}^{b}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial f} - \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial L}{\partial f'} \right)\delta f(x)~dx$$ is this what youre guiding me towards?

Comment: Yup, that's another way of doing it. Think about it, your functional depends on two distinct functions. There are in fact two functional derivatives, one with respect to $x(t)$, another w.r.t $y(t)$. It's just like normal calculus, if you have multiple variables, you get partial derivatives instead of a single derivative.

Comment: the notion makes sense, i think the issue has been the idea of $\delta f(x)$ taking specific values and what the "end result" would look like, it's come to my attention that my confusion may stem on whether or not we let the end points vary or whether they'd be set to zero. Another post i saw just straight up differentiated the Lagrangian. but essentially we've been given no boundary conditions and so i imagine i have to continue with the courses convention that the end points vanish. i guess at this point it's the procedure which has confused me.

Comment: From my current understanding, $f\delta(x)$ acts as a function describing the boundary conditions, and we would consider the increment to see the "variation" between the for lack of a better phrase, "actual" answer and the taylor expanded version. in the sense of an error function. since our end points vanish i can use the Euler-Legrange equation. but if they didn't, then the assumptions which give raise to the EL equation are no longer valid and so the difference must be directly computed? is this right?

Comment: Exactly. The boundary conditions are important, not only in variational calculus, but in any differential equation in general. In this case, we're only interested in paths that start and end at the same point. Removing this condition is equivalent to solving a completely different problem.

Comment: Thank you very much; it's been a long road but i believe i finally "get it".